# Wikipedia suggests that functions exist that are injective and surject without being bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was playing around with the concepts of injectivity, surjectivity, and bijectivity recently.  I used these three Wikipedia articles as references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

The third article on bijection states the following:

- A bijection is a one-to-one (injective) and onto (surjective) mapping of a set X to a set Y.
- A bijection is a function between the elements of two sets, where each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set.

I've encountered these definitions of bijectivity many times before and they're not surprising.  However, the article on injectivity also states the following about injective functions:

- Every element of the function's codomain is the image of at most one element of its domain.

So then let's say we have two sets $X$ and $Y$ with three and two elements respectively.  We have a function $f$ such that $f$ maps exactly one element of $X$ onto one element of $Y$.  Then, by the definition of injectivity above, $f$ should be injective since every element of $Y$ is the image of one or zero (i.e. at most one) elements in $X$.  Of course, $f$ is also non-total.

Now let's rather say that $f$ maps *two* elements of $X$ onto two elements of $Y$.  Then $f$ should not only be injective but also surjective since $Y$ has only two elements and they are both covered by elements in $X$.

Such a function should be considered bijective since it's both injective and surjective.  However, it's incorrect to say that each element of $X$ is paired with exactly one element of $Y$.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: That last function is not a function from $X\to Y$.  It is only defined on a subset of $X$.  And, yes, that subset of $X$ is in bijection with $Y$.

Comment: " We have a function f such that f maps exactly one element of X onto one element of Y."  If $X$ has three elements that is *not* a function.  TO be a function it must map *ALL* (three) elements to (not necessarily distinct nor to all) elment(s) of $Y$.  "Now let's rather say that f maps two elements of X onto two elements of Y."  still not a function.

Comment: .... Or perhaps more accurately.  $f$ is a function that maps $f:\{x\} \to Y$ but $f:X \not \to Y$.  The domain of $f$ is $\{x\} \ne X$.  So Yes the function: $f:\{x\} \to Y$ is injective but $f$ is *not* a function with domain $X$.  And in the second example $f:\{x,w\} \to Y$ is a bijection but again it's domain is $\{x,w\}$ and *not* $X$.  So again, $f:X\not\to Y$.  If $X= \{x,w,v\}$ then to have a function $f:X\to Y$ then you must have $f(x),f(w),f(v)$ all be things.  It is impossible for such a function to be injective as $Y$ has only two elements so they can not be all distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly observed that the mappings you constructed are "non-total," or partial, functions. As such, they are only true functions when we restrict the domain to a subset of elements that actually map to an element in the codomain. This restricted domain is called the domain of definition. The partial functions you described are injective and bijective, respectively.

If the domain is not restricted, then the mappings you have constructed are NOT functions, since there exists an element in the domain that maps to nothing. And, since they are not functions, they cannot be injections nor bijections **because these terms are defined on functions.**

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I found those articles a bit confusing since I wasn't aware that "function" and "total function" were synonymous terms in that context.  I mostly live in software land so partial functions are something I'm always dealing with.

Comment: No problem! And yeah that makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

> " We have a function f such that f maps exactly one element of X onto one element of Y."

If X has three elements that is not a function. TO be a function it must map ALL (three) elements to (not necessarily distinct nor to all) elment(s) of Y.

> "Now let's rather say that f maps two elements of X onto two elements of Y."

still not a function.

======

.... Or perhaps more accurately:

$f$ is a function that maps $f:\{x\} \to Y$ but $f:X \not \to Y$.

The domain of $f$ is $\{x\} \ne X$.  So Yes the function: $f:\{x\} \to Y$ is injective but $f$ is *not* a function with domain $X$.

And in the second example $f:\{x,w\} \to Y$ is a bijection but again it's domain is $\{x,w\}$ and *not* $X$.  So again, $f:X\not\to Y$.

If $X= \{x,w,v\}$ then to have a function $f:X\to Y$ then you must have $f(x),f(w),f(v)$ all be things.  It is impossible for such a function to be injective as $Y$ has only two elements so they can not be all distinct.

> Such a function should be considered bijective since it's both injective and surjective. However, it's incorrect to say that each element of X is paired with exactly one element of Y

Yes, but the "solution" is that $X$ is *not* the domain of those functions.

This would be... *cue condescending chuckle and patronzing looking down the nose of*..... If $X= \mathbb R \cup \{Babar, the elephant\}$ and $f:X \to (0,\infty)$ via $f(x) = e^x$ then $f$ is injective  ($e^x = e^y \iff x=y$) and surjective (if $y \in (0, \infty)$ then $\ln y$ exists and if $x = \ln y$ then $e^x = y$) but $f$ is not bijective because not every element of $X$ is mapped to exactly one element of $Y$ as $Babar, the elephant$ is not mapped to an element of $Y$.

*condescendingly chuckles and walks off congratulating himself for so cleverly making a fool of a smart and earnest and intelligent student who had the audacity of asking an intelligent question*

> So what am I missing here?

Just that every element *of the domain* of $f$ has to be mapped to exactly one element of $Y$.  ANd $X$ is not  .....*trips over a dead horse he's been beating for over 7 paragraphs*  .... the domain of $f$.